# Existence from Energy estimate for hyperbolic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, hyperbolic-equations

Consider a Cauchy problem
$$
   Lu(t,x)=0, \quad u(0,x)=g(x), \quad(t,x)\in[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n
$$
for a symmetric linear hyperbolic operator $L$. Suppose that we can prove an energy estimate of the form
$$
    \Vert u(t,\cdot) \Vert_{H^s} \leq C \Vert g \Vert_{H^s}, \quad t \in [0,T].
$$

How does one infer the following

(i).   Existence of solution
(ii).  Finite propagation speed of the solution

from the energy estimate. Once the existence is established the uniqueness follows immediately.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1992032/532409